# How to get the First day and last day of the month from given month number and year in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a month number and year: month 2 and year 2022.

How can I get the first day of that month like 2022-02-01 and last day of month 2022-02-28?

I have seen many posts on getting first and last date of month based on given date or the current date, but I need it based on given month and year.

Thanks in advance

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Rpt_ItemsSales_DayMonthYear_year]-- 2022
    @year int = NULL
AS
    ;WITH months(MonthNumber) AS
    (
        SELECT 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT MonthNumber + 1
        FROM months
        WHERE MonthNumber < 12
    )
    SELECT
        SalesPos_Dtls.ItemName,
        SUM(SalesPos_Dtls.Qty) AS SumQty,
        SUM(SalesPos_Dtls.TotalPrice) AS SumTotal,
        SalesPos_Dtls.ItemCode,
        DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, m.MonthNumber, 0) - 1) AS MonthName,
        m.MonthNumber
    FROM
        months AS m
    LEFT JOIN
        SalesPos ON MONTH(SalesPos.StartDate) = m.MonthNumber 
                 AND (status = 'IsPosted') 
                 AND (@year = YEAR(salespos.startdate) OR @year IS NULL)
    LEFT JOIN 
        [dbo].SalesPos_Dtls ON SalesPos.ID = SalesPos_Dtls.OrderId 
    GROUP BY
        m.MonthNumber, dbo.SalesPos_Dtls.ItemName, dbo.SalesPos_Dtls.ItemCode
```

And this is as far as I got

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Rpt_ItemsSales_DayMonthYear_year] --2022,1
    @year int = NULL,
    @month int = NULL
AS
    DECLARE @yearr int = @year
    DECLARE @monthh int = @month

    ;WITH months(MonthNumber) AS
    (
        SELECT 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT MonthNumber + 1
        FROM months
        WHERE MonthNumber < 12
    )
    SELECT 
        SalesPos_Dtls.ItemName,
        SUM(SalesPos_Dtls.Qty) AS SumQty,
        SUM(SalesPos_Dtls.TotalPrice) AS SumTotal,
        SalesPos_Dtls.ItemCode,
        DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, m.MonthNumber, 0) - 1) AS MonthName,
        m.MonthNumber,
        DATEFROMPARTS (@yearr, @monthh, 1) AS MonthStart,
        EOMONTH (DATEFROMPARTS (@yearr, @monthh, 1)) AS MonthEnd
    FROM
        months AS m
    LEFT JOIN
        SalesPos ON MONTH(SalesPos.StartDate) = m.MonthNumber 
                 AND (status = 'IsPosted') 
                 AND (@year = YEAR(salespos.startdate) OR @year IS  NULL)
    LEFT JOIN 
        [dbo].SalesPos_Dtls ON SalesPos.ID = SalesPos_Dtls.OrderId 
    WHERE
        (MONTH(SalesPos.StartDate) = @month OR @month IS NULL)
    GROUP BY
        m.MonthNumber, dbo.SalesPos_Dtls.ItemName, dbo.SalesPos_Dtls.ItemCode
```

Screenshot with the sample data:

[image: data]

But I want my data this way :

```
هوت دوج  لارج   3.0000  75.0000 

76  January 1   2022-1-01   2022-1-31

هوت دوج ميديم   1.0000  20.0000 77  January 1   2022-1-01   2022-1-31

NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    February    2   2022-2-01   2022-2-28

NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    March   3   NULL    2022-3-01    2022-3-31
```

Comment: As in day you mean the day name yeah?

Comment: `DATEFROMPARTS` and `EOMONTH` is exactly what you want. Why are they not working for you?

Comment: no i mean the day date 2022-1-01

Comment: i truly have no idea why it isn't showing anydata

Comment: And when `@month` is supplied but not `@year`, do you want {that month} for every year? And when neither is supplied it needs to be all time? What about when neither value is supplied? Can it be {last 5 years} or something a little more specific? Could you hard-code the earliest year you want reported on in either of those cases?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET DATEFIRST 1

DECLARE @Month  smallint= 3, @Year   smallint = 2022;

/*First and Last day of month as DATE */
select   DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, @MONTH, 1)FirstDayOfMonth , EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, @MONTH, 1)) LastDayofMonth

/*First and Last Weekday of Month */
select  DATEPART( dw, DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, @MONTH, 1) ) FirstWeekDayOfMonth , DATEPART(dw, (EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, @MONTH, 1)))) LastWeekDayofMonth
```

Comment: i want it as dateType and this give me the day of the week but i want the day of the month 1-31/28

Comment: Added both solutions first query will give you first and last day of month, second one first and last day of week.

Comment: hi taimur , thank you i made a comment with the solution that worked for me but i'm interested to know what is the difference between it and yours if you may explain it for me

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if this is the right way to update the question but here is the solution that worked for me.

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @mydate), 0) AS StartOfMonth
SELECT EOMONTH(@mydate) as LastOFMonth
```

And thanks
edit:
this is the stored procedure. all i wanted is to have 2 columns infront of each item that have the firstday of the month and the last day witch this item was purchased.
i hope this and the stored procedure explain what i mean.

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[Rpt_ItemsSales_DayMonthYear_year]--Rpt_ItemsSales_DayMonthYear_year 2022
@year int=null
as
;WITH months(MonthNumber) AS
(
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MonthNumber+1
    FROM months
    WHERE MonthNumber < 12
)
select SalesPos_Dtls.ItemName,sum(SalesPos_Dtls.Qty) as SumQty,sum(SalesPos_Dtls.TotalPrice) as SumTotal,SalesPos_Dtls.ItemCode,DateName( month , DateAdd( month , m.MonthNumber , 0 ) - 1 ) as MonthName,
m.MonthNumber, cast(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, SalesPos.StartDate), 0) as date) AS StartOfMonth,EOMONTH(SalesPos.StartDate) as LastOFMonth
from months as m
left join SalesPos on month(SalesPos.StartDate) = m.MonthNumber and (status = 'IsPosted') and (@year = year(salespos.startdate) or @year is null)
left JOIN [dbo].SalesPos_Dtls  on SalesPos.ID=SalesPos_Dtls.OrderId 
group by m.MonthNumber,dbo.SalesPos_Dtls.ItemName,dbo.SalesPos_Dtls.ItemCode,cast(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, SalesPos.StartDate), 0) as date),EOMONTH(SalesPos.StartDate)
```

Comment: That is categorically worse than `DATEFROMPARTS`, and you don't explain _why_ that "worked." How did that work when the existing code didn't? Why do you assign `@yearr = @year` anyway? What is the purpose of an extra pair of variables? Also where did `@mydate` come from? It's not in the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: hi arron, i updated my comment and sorry for any misunderstanding